# Amazon Kindle Whispersync behaviour

Tags: sync, kindle

Can anyone shed any light on how Whispersync works on a Kindle 4 (Non-touch)

I often read with my Kindle with the wifi network turned off to preserve battery life. I will turn it on when I am expecting a new document to be received, but then I turn it back off again. I have a number of books on the go at once, so will often had read different sections in multiple books with the wifi off. I also read on the Android Kindle app, sometimes the same books, sometimes different books.

When I turn the wifi back on does the Kindle automatically sync my read progress, notes and highlights, or do I have to manually select the Sync menu option? Assuming it’s automatic, will it sync these items for all books on the kindle, or just the book I have open at the time?

R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It syncs automatically when you turn wireless on, including positions in all books and notes/highlights.

Comment: So just the act of connecting on Wifi starts a sync? You don't need to go into or out of any documents on the device?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to do anything.

You can go to the menu and select "sync and check for items" to force a sync, but I don't think I've ever needed to do that.